# how to force Vite (rollup) imported constructs replace by module code itself

Tags: import, vite, rollup, rollupjs

The essence of the problem is that the vite (rollup) in the final build leaves import constructs, this happens when the same node module is imported more than 1 time in the project. How can I make vite insert the node module code itself instead of the import construct?

I tried different Rollup and Vite plugins, but did not get any results.